# Can I use Bootstrap with RCloud?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, branding, rcloud

Although Shiny is great, I would really like to make my own responsive dashboard and use custom branding, so can I use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) in [RCloud](http://rcloud.social/index.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods of adding CSS in RCloud, including:

**Method 1.**

In a **edit.html/view.html** notebook (standard notebook interface), add the CSS as an RCloud Asset and use:

```
 rcloud.install.css(paste0("/notebook.R/",rcloud.session.notebook.id(),"/simple.css"))
```

Note: This assumes the RCloud Asset is in the same notebook. If not, the **notebook.R** path would need to be specified.  [notebook.R](https://github.com/att/rcloud/wiki/notebook.R-API) serves two purposes, 1. serve notebooks as "scripts" processing REST API, serve static assets from notebooks (e.g., the CSS).

**Method 2.**

In a [mini.html](https://github.com/att/rcloud/wiki/mini.html) notebook:

```
library(rcloud.web) 
html.main <- rcloud.get.asset("method1.html", notebook =rcloud.session.notebook.id())
rcw.result(body=html.main)
```

where method1.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/notebook.R/236f9f7e41045780d00f9dbd08b8a890/simple.css">
</head>
<body>
etc.
```

**Method 3.**

In a mini.html notebook, use the body parameter of rcw.result to add direct HTML:

```
library(rcloud.web) 
rcw.result( 
body="<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src='/notebook.R/e8c8df5eff2161b309213b8f7e7cafd6/simple.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/notebook.R/e8c8df5eff2161b309213b8f7e7cafd6/simple.css' media='screen'/>
<div id=left-margin>A very simple notebook.
<p id=demo>It worked!</p>
<button class=intro type='button' onclick='myFunction()'>Click me</button></div>"
)
```

**Note:** The inner quotes must be single quotes. There are other permutations of this and you can also add Javascript and JS libraries (e.g., D3 and JQuery) the same way - which is nice, especially since mini.html can register callbacks and has a running RCloud session available as long as the page is open.

Comment: In addition, in `edit.html` and `view.html`, any assets named `rcloud-*.css` will be automatically loaded into the `<head>` element (before any content is loaded). This is very much like **Method 1** but loads earlier.